# brew install nginx,how to change nginx.conf file location?

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew

```
 brew install  openresty  --with-debug --conf-path=/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

but it no effect.

```
nginx -V
nginx version: openresty/1.9.7.4 (no pool)
built by clang 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: ......--conf-path=/usr/local/etc/openresty/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-dtrace-probes --with-http_ssl_module
```

the nginx.conf file location not changed,still is the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option you have specified `--conf-path` is not a `homebrew` supported option. You can see that by running this:

```
brew options openresty
```

**Output**

```
--with-debug
    Compile with support for debug logging but without proper gdb debugging symbols
--with-geoip
    Compile with ngx_http_geoip_module
--with-gunzip
    Compile with ngx_http_gunzip_module
--with-iconv
    Compile with support for converting character encodings
--with-postgresql
    Compile with support for direct communication with PostgreSQL database servers
--with-stub_status
    Compile with ngx_http_stub_status_module
--with-webdav
    Compile with ngx_http_dav_module
--without-luajit
    Compile *without* support for the Lua Just-In-Time Compiler
```

I think the only way to do what you want is to edit the formula, so you would do:

```
brew edit openresty
```

and then search down for `conf-path`, and edit the part that looks like this:

```
args = [
  "--prefix=#{prefix}",
  "--pid-path=#{var}/run/openresty.pid",
  "--lock-path=#{var}/run/openresty.lock",
  "--sbin-path=#{bin}/openresty",
  "--conf-path=#{etc}/openresty/nginx.conf",        <--- HERE
  "--http-log-path=#{var}/log/nginx/access.log",
  "--error-log-path=#{var}/log/nginx/error.log",
  "--with-pcre",
  "--with-pcre-jit",
  "--with-cc-opt=#{cc_opt}",
  "--with-ld-opt=#{ld_opt}",
]
```

You may need to do:

```
brew tap homebrew/nginx
```

before running the above commands.